# python - what does yield (yield) do?

Tags: python, generator, yield

Since python 2.5 there is the ability to `send()`, `throw()`, `close()` into a generator. Inside the defined generator one can 'catch' the sent data by doing something like:

```
def gen():
    while True:
        x = (yield)
        if x == 3:
            print('received 3!!')
            break
        else:
            yield x
```

What i am trying to play with is doing something like:

```
def gen2():
    while True:
        yield (yield)
```

Noticed that it is a legal generator which does something.. 
First thing i'm trying to figure out is:

**Is there a good usage for such writing?**

Also when doing something like:

```
g = gen2()
next(g)
g.send(10) # output: 10
g.send(2) # output: nothing
g.send(3) # output: 3
g.send(44) # output: nothing
```

**Why each second 'send' does not do anything?**

Comment: hard to reproduce: I get "StopIteration" at send(3)..., that is when I switch `gen2` by `gen`

Comment: also is your question "what does yield (yield) do?" (I can answer that) or "Why each second 'send' do not do anything?" (I can't answer that)

Comment: @Jean-FrançoisFabre I get exactly what he showed.

Comment: For your example with the various `.send` calls, are you referring to "output" that occurs when you execute type these commands one by one at the interactive prompt?  If you run your code non-interactively, there will be no output at all.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

`yield (yield)` first yields `None` from the inner `yield`. It then receives a value from `send` or `next`. The inner `yield` evaluates to this received value, and the outer `yield` promptly yields that value.

---

Each `yield` conceptually has two parts:

1. Transmit a value to the caller of `send` or `next`.
2. Receive a value from the next `send` or `next` call.

Similarly, each `send` or `next` conceptually has two parts:

1. Transmit a value to the `yield` expression that the generator is currently paused at. (This value is `None` for `next`.)
2. Receive a value from the next `yield` expression.

The most confusing part of the system is probably that these parts are staggered. The two parts of a `yield` correspond to two different invocations of `send` or `next`, and the two parts of a `send` or `next` correspond to two different `yield`s.

**If we work through a simple example:**

```
def gen():
    print('Not ran at first')
    yield (yield)

g = gen()  # Step 1
print(next(g))  # Step 2
print(g.send(1))  # Step 3
g.send(2)  # Step 4
```

Here's how things work out:

```
Inside the generator                      Outside the generator
```

**Step 1**

```
                                          g calls gen()
g returns a generator object 
without executing the print
just yet statement.
                                          >>> g
                                          <generator object gen at 0x7efe286d54f8>
```

**Step 2**

```
                                          next(g) sends None to g
g receives None, ignores it
  (since it is paused at the start
   of the function)

g prints ('not ran at first')

g executes the "transmit" phase
  of the inner yield, transmitting
  None
                                          next(g) receives None
```

**Step 3**

```
                                          g.send(1) sends 1 to g
g executes the "receive" phase
  of the inner yield, receiving 1
g executes the "transmit" phase
  of the outer yield, transmitting 1
                                          g.send(1) receives 1 from g
```

**Step 4**

```
                                          g.send(2) sends 2 to g
g executes the "receive" phase
  of the outer yield, receiving 2
g reaches the end of gen and raises
  a StopIteration
                                          g.send(2) raises the StopIteration
                                          from g
```

Answer (score 3):

`yield` is an expression.  The value of the expression is the value of whatever was sent using `.send`, or None if nothing was sent (including if `next` was used instead of `.send`).  `.send` is a method call and thus of course also returns a value, which is the value yielded by the generator.  In other words, every time you `.send`, a value (which may be None) is yielded, and every time you `yield`, a value (which may be None) is sent.

Here is a simple example:

```
def gen():
    sent1 = yield 1
    print(sent1, "was sent")
    sent2 = yield 2
    print(sent2, "was sent")
    print("Reached end of generator")

g = gen()
print(next(g), "was yielded")
print(g.send("A"), "was yielded")
print(g.send("B"), "was yielded")
next(g)

# output
1 was yielded
A was sent
2 was yielded
B was sent
Reached end of generator
# StopIteration is raised here
```

In your example, the first `next` yields None, since the first `yield` is the inner yield in `yield (yield)` (i.e., the one in parentheses).  The first `send` passes 10 as the value this `yield`.  Each subsequent value that you `send` becomes the value of one of the yields.  The reason some of your `send` calls produce no output is that the inner yield specifies no value, so it yields `None`.  As mentioned above, when you call `send`, a value is yielded; in your case, that value is None for the inner yield, so no output is displayed at the interactive prompt.  The outer yield, on the other hand, does specify a value, namely the result of the inner yield.  So when you `send` a value in to the inner `yield`, it will be yielded by the outer `yield` at the next iteration.  (I'm assuming you're referring to output at the interactive prompt; if you run your code as a script, there will be no output at all, since you never `print` anything or otherwise produce explicit output.)

Here is another example that may be illuminating:

```
def gen():
    yield (yield (yield (yield "WHOA")))

>>> g = gen()
>>> next(g)
'WHOA'
>>> g.send(1)
1
>>> g.send(2)
2
>>> g.send(3)
3
>>> g.send(4)
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<pyshell#11>", line 1, in <module>
    g.send(4)
StopIteration
```

Notice that each time a value is sent in, it is immediately yielded back.  This is because each `yield` yields the value of a more-deeply-nested `yield`.  Each `yield` "becomes" the sent value and is immediately yielded by the next `yield` in the chain.  This continues until all yields are exhausted and StopIteration is raised.

Similar questions about this have been asked before.  My impression is that confusion tends to arise because people expect `send` to "just send" a value.  But that is not the case.  Using `send` advances the generator and yields the next result, just like using `next`.  You can think of `next(gen)` as equivalent to `gen.send(None)`.